# gclient sync doesn't do anything

Tags: chromium

I'm running the command:

```
gclient sync --no-history -j1
```

However, nothing is happening. Normally the Chromium repositories would sync, but nothing is happening. I have a .gclient file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command doesn't print information about progress first ~20-30 minutes. Just wait for a while and you will see sync progress. In my environment it takes ~30 minutes until I see progress in terminal.

Comment: is there any way to get progress to print earlier? i'm writing a bash script to build chromium from source and 30 minutes of no feedback is weird! - i notice that if i ctrl+c i do see some output to the console from `git`, how can i capture that and force it to display?

Comment: You can try "gclient sync -j1 -v"